# How do I write a script to read a matrix from a mtx file using the function scipy.io.mmread?

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have been given a file (called matrix.mtx), that when opened looks like this:

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate real symmetric  
132 132 1890  
1 1  1.9960268182200e+03  
2 1  5.6751562001600e+02  
3 1  7.7541907594400e+02  
6 1 -8.0165406828800e+02  
7 1 -1.3864718750000e+03  
13 1 -1.2338727484800e+00  
18 1 -5.9225891927100e+02  
19 1 -4.9040995231500e+02  
20 1 -4.8997371242200e+02
```

... and so on down

I need to write a script that will read the matrix from the file matrix.mtx using the function scipy.io.mmread. This function will store the matrix in a sparse format. It says the matrix is stored in the Matrix Market format. I am having trouble getting it to work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Using the following simpler matrix, also stored in `matrix.mtx`,

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate real symmetric
3 3 6
1 1  1.9960268182200e+03
2 1  5.6751562001600e+02
3 1  7.7541907594400e+02
2 2 -8.0165406828800e+02
3 2 -1.3864718750000e+03
3 3 -5.9225891927100e+02
```

the following reads the file into a sparse matrix

```
In [1]: from scipy.io import mmread

In [2]: a = mmread('matrix.mtx')

In [3]: a
Out[3]:
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

and one can then transform it into a dense matrix

```
In [4]: a.todense()
Out[4]:
matrix([[ 1996.02681822,   567.51562002,   775.41907594],
        [  567.51562002,  -801.65406829, -1386.471875  ],
        [  775.41907594, -1386.471875  ,  -592.25891927]])
```

or an array

```
In [5]: a.toarray()
Out[5]:
array([[ 1996.02681822,   567.51562002,   775.41907594],
       [  567.51562002,  -801.65406829, -1386.471875  ],
       [  775.41907594, -1386.471875  ,  -592.25891927]])
```